# How can I compare multiple rows with other rows from two different table and check if they are equal or not?

Tags: sql-server, dynamicquery

I have 2 table named `OptionText` and `SubmittedAns` The first table contains the `QuestionId` `OptionId` and `IsRight`. Here `IsRight` is used for either the options against the question is either right or wrong.Here a `QuestionId` have multiple `OptionId` even can have one too.  The second table represent what is submitted by the user. They can either select one option or multiple option based on their assumption. Now I need to make automatic script which will justify either the submitted answers against right or wrong.

**Note: If a question have more than one correct option then the user have to select all right option, if one is missing then the result will be false. However if he selects all right answers then the answer will be true.**

I have tried through this [script](http://rextester.com/live/DAA59119). It's just able to count the selected numbers but can't justify the answer is either right or wrong. So I need help.

I can assume that I need a `WHILE` loop to check each element particularly. But how? So I need help. Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE OptionText(
    [OptionTextId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IsRightAnswer] [bit] NOT NULL)

    Insert into OptionText (QuestionId, IsRightAnswer) VALUES (5, 1)    
    Insert into OptionText (QuestionId, IsRightAnswer) VALUES (5, 0)   
    Insert into OptionText (QuestionId, IsRightAnswer) VALUES (5, 0)

    Insert into OptionText (QuestionId, IsRightAnswer) VALUES (17, 0)    
    Insert into OptionText (QuestionId, IsRightAnswer) VALUES (17, 1)   
    Insert into OptionText (QuestionId, IsRightAnswer) VALUES (17, 1)

CREATE TABLE SubmittedAns(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OptionTextId] [bigint] NOT NULL)


    Insert into SubmittedAns (QuestionId, OptionTextId) VALUES (5, 1)    
    Insert into SubmittedAns (QuestionId, OptionTextId) VALUES (5, 2)

    Insert into SubmittedAns (QuestionId, OptionTextId) VALUES (2, 1)
    Insert into SubmittedAns (QuestionId, OptionTextId) VALUES (2, 1)


    select * from OptionText
    select * from SubmittedAns
    if (select count(OptionTextId) from SubmittedAns where QuestionId =5) = (select count(ot.OptionTextId) from OptionText as ot  where ot.IsRightAnswer = 1)
     select 1  as "isRight"
    else
     select 0  as "isRight"
```

Comment: add your expected output

Comment: It will just return either it's right ans or wrong ans. I mean `0/1`

Comment: If question 3 has options 1, 2 and 4 right, but option 5 wrong, then user must select **only** options 1, 2 and 4 so that his answer is considered correct, he cannot select 1, 2, 5, he cannot select 1, 2, 4, 7, he cannot select 1, 2, 4, 5. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, @KtX2SkD you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to first & last line for critical material:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS Boolean
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #OptionText
    WHERE QuestionId = 5
      AND IsRightAnswer = 1
) AS OT
FULL OUTER JOIN #SubmittedAns AS SA ON OT.QuestionId = SA.QuestionId AND OT.OptionTextId = SA.OptionTextId
WHERE SA.QuestionId = 5
  AND OT.OptionTextId IS NULL -- This means some answers failed to be matched with your original questions/options, either because IsRightAnswer is zero, or because it doesn't exist in your questions/answers.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution on my way of understanding. So I have used a function to apply it for all question and created this code. It's working.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Set_IsCorrect_Answer_Deva]
(
    @QuestionId BIGINT
)
RETURNS  BIT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @IsRightAns BIT
DECLARE @count int

set @IsRightAns = 0
Declare @supplied_count int
select @supplied_count = Count(*) from SuppliedAnswersTemp where QuestionId=@QuestionId

 IF(@supplied_count>0)
    Begin
        IF(@supplied_count=(select Count(*) from OptionText where QuestionId=@QuestionId and IsRightAnswer=1))
            Begin
                    select @count=Count(*) from OptionText ot join  SuppliedAnswersTemp sa on ot.QuestionId = sa.QuestionId
                     where ot.QuestionId= @QuestionId and ot.IsRightAnswer =1 and ot.Id=sa.OptionId
            END
END

IF(@count>0)
    Set @IsRightAns=1

RETURN   @IsRightAns
END
```

Comment: Are you sure of this? It seems to only compare the counts between options and answers. Also, you can go with `OR` instead of nesting `IF`. Lastly, I hope you checked the edit on my answer.

Comment: I have seen your. Ans. Moreover I have used your ans in my project too. But, in my way I got a solution too. Therefore I have shared.

Comment: No problems, appreciate the sharing, just wanted to double-check it works, and to make sure you saw both answer versions :)